# Can Rundeck Be Configured to Use Different Nodes If Someone Else is Already Running A Job On Current Node?

Tags: rundeck

I am trying to see if rundeck is capable of deciding if a node is currently busy runnning another job and it will switch to another node and ruin the job there instead.

For example, I am current running a job on NODE1, then another person logs into rundeck and decide to run their job on NODE1, but NODE1 is busy running my job so rundeck will automatically run their job on NODE2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible assuming the following design:

1) Create/use a resource model source plugin that sets attributes about the node's business. This can be a metric like load status or something else that you use to gauge rundeck utilization.

2) Write the job with a nodefilter to match on the attribute about utilization metric

3 ) Define the job to use the RandomSubset Orchestration strategy specifying to use 1 node.